# What template variable does django-crispy-forms use for formset forms?

Tags: django-crispy-forms

I have the following in my template code:

```
{% crispy form.meters_formset form.meters_formset.form.helper %}
```

This renders a formset that is an instance variable of my form.  This is how I handle forms with embedded formsets.

In the helper for the formset's form (`form.meters_formset.form.helper`), I have an `HTML` element in the layout in which I would like to access the instance attached to that formset form.  How would I do this?  Crispy forms must be doing a for loop to loop through the formset's forms, but what template variable is it using?

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this problem by replacing

```
{% crispy form.meters_formset form.meters_formset.form.helper %}
```

with

```
{% for subform in form.meters_formset %}
{% crispy subform %}
{% endfor %}
```

and accessing the instance with `{{ subform.instance }}`.